# Screen density qualifiers

Tags: android

There is `hdpi` and `nodpi` qualifier folders in my project. Suppose I have installed the app in a `hdpi` density device. From which qualifier folder will it pick the resources ?

Comment: Try to place two different images with the same name in hdpi and nodpi folder. You will find out from which folder it is picking the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the hdpi resources will be used. Device will first check the corresponding dpi resource folder.

according to [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

> 1. The system uses the appropriate alternative resource Based on the size and density of the current screen, the system uses any size- and
>      density-specific resource provided in your application. For example,
>      if the device has a high-density screen and the application requests a
>      drawable resource, the system looks for a drawable resource directory
>      that best matches the device configuration. Depending on the other
>      alternative resources available, a resource directory with the hdpi
>      qualifier (such as drawable-hdpi/) might be the best match, so the
>      system uses the drawable resource from this directory.
> 2. If no matching resource is available, the system uses the default resource and scales it up or down as needed to match the current
>      screen size and density.

the nodpi resources are also default resources type. The only difference is it doesn't scall the images but drawable does.

Answer (score 1):

**drawable-nodpi**: This can be used for bitmap resources that you do not want to be scaled to match the device density.

if you have an images with same name in hdpi and nodpi drawable folder when you are running in hdpi it will pick from HDPI darwable only.

There is an image with `100 x 100 px` that I want to show in any resolution/density as same size then we need the `drawable-nodpi` folder.